# Error when updating json data using http put in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, http-put

Why am i getting this

PUT file:///C:/Users/User/Documents/Work/someapi/word/15 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
when i am updating

```
$http({
    url: url + Id,
    method: "PUT", //update
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
      Id: '154',
      word: $scope.new,
      Date: new Date(),
    }),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/JSON'
    }

  })
  .success(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  })
```

am not updating a file . am confused.

Comment: Can you please share the URL which are you setting up?

Comment: @Chander.k thank you, the url address was missing http:// :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if URL is valid. make sure you are using `http://`,`https://` in URL